# Remote DB get connection string

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm developing a C# program that uses a sql server DataBase.

I Want to move the DB file to another computer\server.

How will i know what is the connection string after I moved the file?

Comment: You can't use "in file" db located on different server.

Comment: What does your connection string look like right now (before the actual moving)

Comment: How are you getting your connection string now?

Comment: "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Yogev\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\YNIDS\\YNIDS\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;";

Comment: @AdrianSalazar do you know the answer to my problem?

Comment: @Yogevnn you've got some answers. The changes in the connection string are trivial. I would focus however, on setting up sql server in the remote machine for accepting remote incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather comment this but my rep is low so I can't. I'll give the answer a shot with a big assumption - that you are using Visual Studio.

A simple way to do this in Visual Studio is to create a new data source and then snip the string from the wizard.

I'm assuming you use VS. Instructions below are for VS2013. This should work for VS2010 and 2012 as well.

If you don't already have "DataSources" tab on screen:
1. In menu go to "View" then "Other Windows" then  "DataSources"
2. In DataSources, click the "Add new Data Source" icon.
3. Navigate the wizard and point the wizard to the new location of your DB based on your circumstances. It will give you the option of showing a connection string that you can copy and paste into your code.

Once you have it, cancel the wizard.

[image: Config Wizard Screen]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think that you missed my point.
Currently my DB is on my computer, and i have a connection string to it, but i need to move it to a distanced server, so how will i know the connection string needed to the server? Should i only change the file path? with the network address of the server and the path inside?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to connect to your database remotely. This means that SQL Server Database is in your computer and Your application is using your database from another computer(remote compute). For this your have to install your application in remote computer and change connection string to this. For this you need to have public IP.

```
"Data Source=91.200.216.15(Your public IP),1433(TCP port of SQL Server).\SQLEXPRESS(YourInstanceName);Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;"
```

Second, if you want to install sql server engine and attach your database in distance computer. It means database and application are on the distance computer. In this case you only change your connection string. When you install sql server express by default its instance name is sqlexpress and .\ mean your computer name. Just change your connection string and run your app.

```
"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;"
```

Do not use attachDBFile as it slows down your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main points to consider for accessing the database via a connection string:

1. What server is it hosted on?
2. Is it a named instance?
3. What database are we connecting to?

In your connection string you are connecting to your local SQL Express server, on the default instance, and attaching a specific file as the database.

So from your connection string:

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Yogev\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\YNIDS\\YNIDS\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;
```

The three details are:

1. `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;`
2. (No instance specified, i.e. default instance)
3. `AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\...\\Database.mdf;`

Normally you wouldn't use the specific filename as the location/filename can change.

To get the required details do the following:

1. Open SQLExpress
2. In `Object Explorer` right-click on the top node (the server name) and select properties
3. The name is specified in the format `Servername\Instancename`
4. Cancel the server properties dialog
5. Expand the `Databases` node and note the name of your database

Assuming the database name is `Database` we can change your connection string to the following:

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;
```

The main difference here is we're not specifying the specific filename and file location.

If you have access to the new server you can get the IP address of the server using the command `ipconfig` in a command line prompt then gather details as above, or ask whoever is responsible for the server to tell you the IP and server details.

Armed with this information, you simply change the `Data Source` to point to the new server (as mentioned by Firdavs Kurbonov) like so:

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;
```

*Note I used `127.0.0.1` to illustrate where the IP address for the server goes, but `127.0.0.1` would point to your local instance*.

If the new server is a named instance, change this to:

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1\Instancename;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;
```

*Where `Instancename` is the actual name of the SQL Server instance*.

The final thing to check is the security details; our connection string thus far is assuming windows authentication (which is recommended).

If required you can provide `user id` and `password` details as follows:

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1\Instancename;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword;
```

I recommend checking out [connectionstrings.com](https://connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for more details on creating connection strings.